Does adaptive randomisation in RCT bias estimates?
I am reading a book on RCT in Education, and it says some studies use adaptive schemes, basically taking into account covariates that are deemed to be able to influence outcomes (eg pre-intervention test scorse) to alter the chance of being assigned to control or treatment group and guarantee the two groups characteristic distribution.
An example of so called block randomisation is to pair schools based on their ranking in math scores and then randomly assign one to treat and one to control.
I'm inclined to think this bias results because it changes the distribution from which we are drawing the subjects, even though each group characteristics empirical distribution more closely resembles the population as a whole. I mean, unbalanced groups are part of the random draws we can get.
But this seems accepted practice and maybe reduces the type I error as claimed and I'm missing something?
